# Unsupported class file major version 65 with Java21 and Springboot 3.2.1 while generating tests with Spring Cloud Contract Verifier

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-cloud, java-21

**Update-0:**

Create a Github [issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues/2084) on Spring Cloud project

**Original Post:**

I'm having an issue on a Springboot project I'm following

**Environment:**

- Temurin Java21 (also happens with Amazon Corretto)
- Maven 3.9.6
- Macbook M1 Pro (also happens in containers)

**Description:**

The issue appears while generating tests using `spring-cloud-contract-verifier`, it only happens with Java21, reverting to Java17 fixes it. I can easily reproduce the issue doing `mvn clean package`, here's the stacktrace (I had to hide a bunch of paths for privacy reasons):

```
--- spring-cloud-contract:4.1.0:generateTests (default-generateTests) @ project ---
[INFO] Generating server tests source code for Spring Cloud Contract Verifier contract verification
[INFO] Will use contracts provided in the folder [path/to/my/contracts]
[INFO] Directory with contract is present at [/path/to/my/contracts]
[INFO] Test Source directory: /path/to/my/test/sources/contracts added.
[INFO] Using [name.of.my.basecontractclass] as base class for test classes, [null] as base package for tests, [null] as package with base classes, base class mappings []
[ERROR] Exception occurred while trying to evaluate the contract at path [/path/to/my/groovy/file]
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 65
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 65
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:199)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:180)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:287)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmDecompiler.parseClass(AsmDecompiler.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findDecompiled(ClassNodeResolver.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.tryAsLoaderClassOrScript(ClassNodeResolver.java:193)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findClassNode(ClassNodeResolver.java:175)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.resolveName(ClassNodeResolver.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveClassNullable(AsmReferenceResolver.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveClass(AsmReferenceResolver.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.TypeSignatureParser.visitEnd(TypeSignatureParser.java:113)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.signature.SignatureReader.parseType(SignatureReader.java:206)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.signature.SignatureReader.accept(SignatureReader.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.ClassSignatureParser.parseClassSignature(ClassSignatureParser.java:104)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.ClassSignatureParser.configureClass(ClassSignatureParser.java:36)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.lazyInitSupers(DecompiledClassNode.java:222)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.isUsingGenerics(DecompiledClassNode.java:87)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.tools.GenericsUtils.nonGeneric(GenericsUtils.java:297)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.MemberSignatureParser.createMethodNode(MemberSignatureParser.java:107)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.lambda$createMethodNode$1(DecompiledClassNode.java:266)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.createMethodNode(DecompiledClassNode.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.lazyInitMembers(DecompiledClassNode.java:239)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.DecompiledClassNode.getDeclaredMethods(DecompiledClassNode.java:123)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getDeclaredMethods(ClassNode.java:888)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getMethods(ClassNode.java:903)
    at org.apache.groovy.ast.tools.ClassNodeUtils.hasPossibleStaticMethod(ClassNodeUtils.java:252)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.hasPossibleStaticMethod(ClassNode.java:1364)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.findStaticMethod(StaticImportVisitor.java:591)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.findStaticPropertyAccessorByFullName(StaticImportVisitor.java:525)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.findStaticPropertyAccessor(StaticImportVisitor.java:543)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.findStaticPropertyOrField(StaticImportVisitor.java:558)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.findStaticFieldOrPropertyAccessorImportFromModule(StaticImportVisitor.java:411)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transformVariableExpression(StaticImportVisitor.java:221)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transform(StaticImportVisitor.java:121)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transformMethodCallExpression(StaticImportVisitor.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transform(StaticImportVisitor.java:130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.Expression.transformExpressions(Expression.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression.transformExpression(ArgumentListExpression.java:67)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transform(StaticImportVisitor.java:139)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transformMethodCallExpression(StaticImportVisitor.java:246)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transform(StaticImportVisitor.java:130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitExpressionStatement(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:168)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:70)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transformClosureExpression(StaticImportVisitor.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transform(StaticImportVisitor.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.Expression.transformExpressions(Expression.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression.transformExpression(ArgumentListExpression.java:67)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transform(StaticImportVisitor.java:139)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transformMethodCallExpression(StaticImportVisitor.java:246)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transform(StaticImportVisitor.java:130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitExpressionStatement(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:168)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:70)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transformClosureExpression(StaticImportVisitor.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transform(StaticImportVisitor.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.Expression.transformExpressions(Expression.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression.transformExpression(ArgumentListExpression.java:67)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transform(StaticImportVisitor.java:139)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transformMethodCallExpression(StaticImportVisitor.java:246)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.transform(StaticImportVisitor.java:130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitExpressionStatement(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:168)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:70)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:142)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticImportVisitor.visitConstructorOrMethod(StaticImportVisitor.java:104)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitMethods(ClassNode.java:1135)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1128)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.lambda$addPhaseOperations$4(CompilationUnit.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$IPrimaryClassNodeOperation.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:900)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:654)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:628)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:368)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.lambda$parseClass$2(GroovyClassLoader.java:311)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.compute(StampedCommonCache.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.getAndPut(StampedCommonCache.java:154)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:309)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:543)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:556)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:568)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:431)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:475)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.util.ContractVerifierDslConverter.toObject(ContractVerifierDslConverter.java:157)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.util.ContractVerifierDslConverter.convertAsCollection(ContractVerifierDslConverter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.file.ContractFileScanner.appendRecursively(ContractFileScanner.java:130)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.file.ContractFileScanner.findContractsRecursively(ContractFileScanner.java:102)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.TestGenerator.generateTestClasses(TestGenerator.java:131)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.TestGenerator.generate(TestGenerator.java:111)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.maven.verifier.GenerateTestsMojo.execute(GenerateTestsMojo.java:296)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000(MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run(MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute(DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:206)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:348)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
1 error
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors (ErrorCollector.java:295)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addException (ErrorCollector.java:143)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$IPrimaryClassNodeOperation.doPhaseOperation (CompilationUnit.java:934)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations (CompilationUnit.java:654)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile (CompilationUnit.java:628)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass (GroovyClassLoader.java:368)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.lambda$parseClass$2 (GroovyClassLoader.java:311)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.compute (StampedCommonCache.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.getAndPut (StampedCommonCache.java:154)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass (GroovyClassLoader.java:309)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass (GroovyShell.java:543)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse (GroovyShell.java:556)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse (GroovyShell.java:568)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate (GroovyShell.java:431)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate (GroovyShell.java:475)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.util.ContractVerifierDslConverter.toObject (ContractVerifierDslConverter.java:157)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.util.ContractVerifierDslConverter.convertAsCollection (ContractVerifierDslConverter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.file.ContractFileScanner.appendRecursively (ContractFileScanner.java:130)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.file.ContractFileScanner.findContractsRecursively (ContractFileScanner.java:102)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.TestGenerator.generateTestClasses (TestGenerator.java:131)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.TestGenerator.generate (TestGenerator.java:111)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.maven.verifier.GenerateTestsMojo.execute (GenerateTestsMojo.java:296)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
```

The strange thing is that simply packaging the application three times solves the issue. First `mvn package` generates the same exception, the second one too, the third one too, the fourth one is fixed. I see in /target that even if the exception is thrown the stubs get created correctly, obviously doing a `mvn clean` resets the situation. Here's my dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-verifier</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Here's my plugins configuration:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
            <baseClassForTests>path.to.my.basecontract.class</baseClassForTests>
            <testMode>EXPLICIT</testMode>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Every single dependency is up-to-date, I tried to manually update inside the POM every outdated dependency present in spring-cloud-contract-verifier but with no success. Any idea on what is happening? Is java21 simply not supported right now?

Comment: you are working with two Java versions, as it seems: the version in which your classes/libraries are compiled, and the one you're using to run it. The JRE you are using to run it, is older than the version used to compile

Comment: @Stultuske I guess the library I'm using (spring cloud contract verifier) is compiled with an older version of Java, that's what I'm trying to understand. I don't have multiple java versions in my environment.

Comment: no, that's not the issue. The issue is that a library you are trying to use is compiled with a JDK that is newer than the java version on which you are running the code.

Comment: @Stultuske the JDK I'm using to compile and running the project is the same jdk21. So one of the imported .class files is causing this issue, not the ones I'm compiling.

Comment: ... yes, but obviously, those imported libraries and class files have been compiled, too.  Anyway, a little google search has shown that Java 21 IS major version 65, so the cause is: you are not using Java 21 to run the code, you are running it using an older version

Comment: I'm 100% running it with a JDK, I literally ran a docker container with a maven 3.9.5 and temurin 21 in it, same exact issue. I even tried with Amazon Corretto 21.

Comment: As Stultuske already said: The error says (converted to plain English): "You need Java 21 to run this code, but you are using an older version of Java".

Comment: @JFabianMeier as I said before, I'm running jdk21 only, even tried on docker images dedicated with jdk21 and maven 3.9.6, evidently the error message is not saying the truth

Comment: @JFabianMeier In this case, it's not the JDK version of the OP rather an underlying library which is restricted in its compatibility with newer versions of Java.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer – The `spring-cloud-contract-verifier:4.1.0` is not yet compatible with Java-21.

Further details – The groovy version `groovy:4.0.0` that it depends on to compile the classes uses `org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.3` resolved under dependencies which is what is causing it. You could infer that if you follow the stack trace to the classes mentioned and verify the libraries that the respective classes belong to.

Most likely, you would [have to wait](https://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-5.0.html#Groovy5.0-requirements) for the libraries to transitively upgrade and then support the Java version you are moving towards.

Version **[org.ow2.asm:asm:9.5](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.ow2.asm/asm/9.5/jar)** provides the support until class file major version 65.

Comment: I tried to force update org.ow2.asm dependencies to 9.5 manually, still same error though

Comment: @framilanoI I am afraid, you've got to wait for the upgrades then.